# what does someone mean when they say " something passed beyond the limits?"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

I have seen a poem translater of a language but I couldn't get what he translated; 
for example:

> **the Indifference passed beyond the limits**--Nurturer,  how long will I narrate the state of the heart,  and you will say" what's that?

Comment: You need to know what the limits refers to (the limits of *something*).

Answer (score 0):

The translator probably means something more like "the indifference passed beyond my limits" - whoever is talking to the "Nurturer" has had enough of Nurturer's indifference to something.